# Is it possible to create an RNG using an arbitrary-length vector as a seed without creating an entire RNG implementation myself?

Tags: random, rust

This code works fine for vectors of exact length 32 - however, if 32 is changed to some other number, such as 16 or 64, then there is a mismatched type error:

```rust
use rand::{rngs::StdRng, Rng, SeedableRng};
use std::convert::TryInto;

fn generate_random(bytes: Vec<u8>) -> u32 {
    let bytes: [u8; 32] = bytes.try_into().unwrap();
    let mut seeded_rng = StdRng::from_seed(bytes);

    seeded_rng.gen_range(0..32)
}
```

The `rand` docs include [an example for implementing `SeedableRng` for RNGs with large seeds](https://docs.rs/rand/0.8.3/rand/trait.SeedableRng.html#implementing-seedablerng-for-rngs-with-large-seeds), however this is not a complete working example and requires implementing the rest of the RNG (i.e. traits `Rng` and `RngCore`) for a working solution.

Is it possible to create an RNG using an arbitrary-length vector as a seed without creating an entire RNG implementation myself, and if so, how do I go about doing this?

Comment: `bytes.resize(32, 0)`?

Comment: That would work, but would lose entropy in cases where the length is greater than 32

Comment: Perhaps, but if you have more than 32 bytes of entropy, the rng won't be able to take advantage of that anyway. And you should elaborate on what is expected by seeding an rng with arbitrary bytes. If this is for a game or something where the bytes represent a user-generate-able unique code, then perhaps you should hash it into a fixed size before giving it to the rng.

Comment: The eventual goal is to deterministically generate a username, given the bytes of a public key - this is a follow up to my last question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66241471/how-do-i-generate-random-numbers-using-a-seedablerng/66241665

Comment: I'm aware `StdRng` might not be able to use more than 32 bytes of entropy, but in that case I think it may be best to use an RNG capable of doing so, rather than only using some of the public key bytes which could make collision more likely

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a solution which involves using the OpenSSL crate to first make a hash of the N-length vector, then use the resulting hash as the random seed:

```rust
use openssl::sha::Sha256;
use rand::{rngs::StdRng, Rng, SeedableRng};

fn generate_random(bytes: Vec<u8>) -> u32 {
    let mut sha256 = Sha256::new();
    sha256.update(&bytes);

    let hash = sha256.finish();
    let mut seeded_rng = StdRng::from_seed(hash);

    seeded_rng.gen_range(0..32)
}
```

Although the true entropy is still 32 bytes using this method, it ensures that any change to part of the seed bytes causes a different resulting RNG, unlike truncating the vector.

Any hash function which takes an arbitrary length `u8` slice and returns a 32-byte `u8` array could also work in place of `openssl::sha::Sha256`.